# How To Get User Friends List Using Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

How can I retrieve User friends list using facebook c# sdk ? 
And I need To know what permissions allow me to get that information.
Below is my own attempt, but it didn't work:

---

```
    //retrieve all user friends ids & names in 2D array 
    public static string[,] getFriends(string accessToken)
    {
        string[,] friends;
        FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        dynamic friend = fb.Get("me/friends");
        int count = (int)friend.data.Count;
        friends = new string[count, 2];
        for (int i = 0; i <count; i++)
        {
            friends[i, 0] = friend.data[i].id;
            friends[i, 1] = friend.data[i].name;
        }//end for 
        return friends;
    }//end get friends
```

Comment: when you say that code didn't work - what did it do?

Comment: I don't Know ? , So I asked For Help .

Comment: You don't know as in you didn't run it and see the error/result/trace/debug info or you don't know as in you haven't actually run the code and traced it?

Comment: Sir : I asked this question after debugged ant traced the code much more times and spend a lot pf time to search about this but i still didn't know the wrong . I guess the permission lost but this is permission i used (publish_stream,user_groups,manage_pages, read_friendlists,user_friends,friends_about_me,user_about_me)

Comment: I get the  count variable is = 0 , so that the friends array is Empty .

Comment: You will only get friends that are using your app in API v2.0.

Comment: aha that is right Thank You Sir ,But what i can do to get user friends list ?! Can u Help me :) ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need class to get all the data from result that give by Facebook in JSON format.
Then you need gridview to display the data from class.

Here the code to get your friends list:

```
public class MyFriends
    {
        public long uid { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public long? friend_count { get; set; }  //nullable
        public string pic_big { get; set; }
        public string birthday { get; set; }
        public string birthday_date { get; set; }
        public string contact_email { get; set; }
    }

protected void friendsList()
{
    var fb = new FacebookClient("YOUR TOKEN HERE");
    var query = string.Format(@"SELECT uid, username, first_name, last_name, friend_count, pic_big, birthday, birthday_date, contact_email 
                        FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())");

    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
    parameters.q = query;
    dynamic results = fb.Get("/fql", parameters);

    List<MyFriends> q = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyFriends>>(results.data.ToString());

    GridView1.DataSource = q;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```